# round edges of programatic label

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create labels which have all four corners rounded, the label is being created programatically as seen below:

```
    Dim lbl1 As Label = New Label()
    lbl1.AutoSize = False 'allow resizing
    lbl1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl1.Text = newid
    lbl1.Height = 46
    lbl1.Width = 42
    lbl1.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

How would I switch from the square corners to a more XP styled rounding.

Comment: `Application.EnableVisualStyles`

Comment: I was hoping to do it in a more definitive method (what if the user is running without a windows style)

Comment: WPF was designed for styling controls.  If using WinForms, you would probably be better off drawing the border and the label in the parent container.  There are always 3rd party controls to consider, too.  Nothing out of the box, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateRoundRectRgn")> _
        Private Shared Function CreateRoundRectRgn(ByVal iLeft As Integer, ByVal iTop As Integer, ByVal iRight As Integer, ByVal iBottom As Integer, ByVal iWidth As Integer, ByVal iHeight As Integer) As IntPtr
        End Function
```

ex.)

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateRoundRectRgn")> _
    Private Shared Function CreateRoundRectRgn(ByVal iLeft As Integer, ByVal iTop As Integer, ByVal iRight As Integer, ByVal iBottom As Integer, ByVal iWidth As Integer, ByVal iHeight As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim newid$ = "mylabel"
        Dim lbl1 As Label = New Label()
        With lbl1
            lbl1.AutoSize = False 'allow resizing
            lbl1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            lbl1.Text = newid
            lbl1.Height = 46
            lbl1.Width = 42
            lbl1.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
            lbl1.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 2, lbl1.Width - 2, lbl1.Height - 2, 5, 1))
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: TBX_SEARCH is tossing an error for not declared value. what is tbx_search

Comment: LOL!  I edited the post.  TBX_SEARCH was a copy and paste error.  replace with LBL1.

I pulled  this from some code in an older app I worked on.

Comment: almost there, this code seems to be rounding the left top and left bottom but neither of the right corners

Comment: Play with the last two values to tune it for your satisfaction.  
ex.) 2, 2, lbl1.Width - 2, lbl1.Height - 2, **15, 15**

All corners should be rounded with the original settings, but its worth messing with.  I suspect however that you have another control stacked on top of the right side of this label control.  ;-)